# How to make stack variables into an array in IDA Pro

Tags: ida, stack-variables, stack, array

I've got a procedure in IDA Pro with a few local stack variables, but part of them belong to an array. I would like to define the array, but pressing `*` (Create Array) fails, and pressing `Y` (Set Type) just brings up the type for the procedure, not the variable.

The same happens if I hover over an instance of its usage rather than its definition in the function prologue.

Oddly enough I seem to be able to rename them just fine.

How do I define a range of local variables to be an array; or, why is it not working for me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Double click the variable name in the disassembly, or press ctrl-k, to open the stack frame window. You can change your variable types there.

Comment: Thank you! This seems to work fine, it's just too bad that it's not more obvious!